# Extract values from within strings in a list - python

Tags: python, string, list, python-2.7

I have a list in my python code with the following structure:

```
file_info = ['{file:C:\\samples\\123.exe, directory:C:\\}','{file:C:\\samples\\345.exe, directory:C:\\}',...]
```

I want to extract just the file and directory values for every value of the list and print it. With the following code, I am able to extract the directory values:

```
for item in file_info:

    print item.split('directory:')[1].strip('}')
```

But I am not able to figure out a way to extract the 'file' values. The following doesn't work:

```
print item.split('file:')[1].strip(', directory:C:\}')
```

Suggestions? If there is any better method to extract the file and directory values other than this, that would be great too. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide an example `file_info`?

Comment: What?! Does `[{file:file1, directory...` etc. have quotes around it? You write that you have a list of dicts and treat it like a string!

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using a `list` of `dicts` and using what seems to be a string instead?

Comment: Sorry, forgot the quotes.. it's not a list of dicts, it's just a list of strings. So it's file_info = ['{file:file1, directory:dir1}','{file:file2, directory:directory2}',...]

Comment: @user2251144 ok, list of strings. A simple example would help a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the format is exactly the same you've provided, you'd better go with using `re`:

```
import re

file_info = ['{file:file1, directory:dir1}', '{file:file2, directory:directory2}']

pattern = re.compile(r'\w+:(\w+)')
for item in file_info:
    print re.findall(pattern, item)
```

or, using string `replace()`, `strip()` and `split()` (a bit hackish and fragile):

```
file_info = ['{file:file1, directory:dir1}', '{file:file2, directory:directory2}']

for item in file_info:
    item = item.strip('}{').replace('file:', '').replace('directory:', '')
    print item.split(', ')
```

both code snippets print:

```
['file1', 'dir1']
['file2', 'directory2']
```

---

If the `file_info` items are just dumped json items (watch the double quotes), you can use `json` to load them into dictionaries:

```
import json

file_info = ['{"file":"file1", "directory":"dir1"}', '{"file":"file2", "directory":"directory2"}']

for item in file_info:
    item = json.loads(item)
    print item['file'], item['directory']
```

or, [literal_eval()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
from ast import literal_eval

file_info = ['{"file":"file1", "directory":"dir1"}', '{"file":"file2", "directory":"directory2"}']

for item in file_info:
    item = literal_eval(item)
    print item['file'], item['directory']
```

both code snippets print:

```
file1 dir1
file2 directory2
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions! I think the json.loads might be more relevant to my code, so I'll try to restructure file_info. Thanks again :)

Comment: The solutions with json.loads and ast.literal_eval are incorrect since the treatment shown by OP in his/her question reveals that the strings are not as you modified them to make json.load and ast.literal_eval to work.

Comment: @eyquem probably. But, as you can see, I've asked for the example twice :) That's why I've provided several options to choose from depends on the input format. Thanks.

Comment: @user2251144 If you can restructure file_info , you should do it avoiding to repeat 'file' and 'directory' that doesn't bring any interesting information because this info is contained in the fact that the file is always in first position and the directory in second position in the string. In my opinion, you're not in a good process of solving a problem: you try to solve it at the level of the consequences while the problem IMO is at the definition of file_info level. I may be wrong. But that's the characteristics of XY problem to not give full information, origine and consequences.

Comment: Yes , you asked two times. And (s)he didn't edit its question. I don't think it's a good practice to give quantities of soluces to balance the lack of a correct question. What if the file_info is composed of ``'{"file":file1, "directory":"dir1"}'`` ? You should provide a soluce for this case too.

Comment: @eyquem I see your point. I was actually thinking about the strangeness of the format the OP described, but rushed into solving the problem of parsing it instead of telling the OP to rethink it. You are absolutely right.

Comment: I have edited the question with an example for better clarity. Turns out I cannot restructure the list format, so I have to use some sort of strip/replace. Also, literal_eval/eval don't work; it shows invalid syntax at C:\\

Comment: _"literal_eval/eval don't work"_ Eh ! To work, it should be ``"C:\\\\"`` in the string.

Comment: @2251144 Why do you use strip and replace, it's less adapted than a regex IMO

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
import re

regx = re.compile('{\s*file\s*:\s*([^,\s]+)\s*'
                  ','
                  '\s*directory\s*:\s*([^}\s]+)\s*}')

file_info = ['{file:C:\\samples\\123.exe, directory  :  C:\\}',
             '{  file:  C:\\samples\\345.exe,directory:C:\\}'
             ]

for item in file_info:
    print '%r\n%s\n' % (item,
                        regx.search(item).groups())
```

result

```
'{file:C:\\samples\\123.exe, directory  :  C:\\}'
('C:\\samples\\123.exe', 'C:\\')

'{  file:  C:\\samples\\345.exe,directory:C:\\}'
('C:\\samples\\345.exe', 'C:\\')
```